# How to wait for mapCanvas render before taking screenshot?

Tags: pyqgis, rendering

i am trying to iterate over a large list of features and making a screenshot of the selected feature. My problem is that it seems to be a delay between the refreshing of the canvas and the taking of the screenshot. In other words, the screenshot taken does not correspond to feature i but to feature i-1, sometimes i have several identical screenshots. Is it possible to explicitely wait until the rendering is done by the mapCanvas before calling the saveAsImage method?

This is globally the code that i am using to do this task.

```
 for i in range(n):
  layer.select(i)
  iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
  qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().zoomScale(1000)
  iface.mapCanvas().refresh() 
  imgname = '_'.join(['','object',str(i)])
  imgname = ''.join([imgname,'.png'])
  iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(imgname)
```

Comment: have you tried the Atlas functionality in the map composer? That effectively does the same thing, and you get more control over the cartography. Tutorial can be [found here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html)

Comment: Not sure of my answer but ... did u try to paste your "capture code" in the **mapCanvasRefreshed()** signal of the MapCanvas ?
Tell me if it helps ...

Comment: @snaileater i already tried that but qgis freezes.

Comment: @StevenKay i didn't know about this feature, i will check it out. As a temporary solution i used an older version of qgis in which my actual code seems to work as i expect.