# Layer not visible when rendering from Python script in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, rendering

I am running a script from the Python console in QGIS. I have stripped the script down to highlight the problem. Basically, when I render and save an image of a shapefile that is displayed with points they do not appear in the saved image. They will appear in the map canvas (see image below). Interestingly, if I have a vector that I fill (e.g., administrative boundaries) they will be visible in rendered image. Here is a screenshot of the map canvas after running script:

[image]

and here is my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

#input Layer
lyrPts = QgsVectorLayer("SomeFile.shp", "Qflu", "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyrPts)

# create image
img = QImage(QSize(8000, 6000), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

# set image's background color
color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
img.fill(color.rgb())

# create painter
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
render = QgsMapRenderer()

# set layer set
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
lst = layers.keys()
render.setLayerSet(lst)

# set extent
rect = QgsRectangle(lyrPts.extent())
rect.scale(1.1)
render.setExtent(rect)

# set output size
render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())

# do the rendering
render.render(p)

#end rendering
p.end()

# save image
img.save("image.png","png")
```

Answer (score 1):

It look like this was an issue with the image being saved before it was rendered. There is a detailed explanation and workaround by @Matthias Kuhn here: [Wait for canvas to finish rendering before saving image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245840/wait-for-canvas-to-finish-rendering-before-saving-image?rq=1)